# Thread dump and memory dump for JVM

Tags: java, c++, jmap

I am trying to create Memory Dump and Thread Dump without using JDK tools like JMAP or JSTACK.

I am not a java programmer, so not aware much about JDK.

"PROJECT A" is developed using JAVA so JRE is a minimal requirement to RUN it.
In JRE, tools like JMAP or JSTACK may not be present. I read somewhere that latest JRE has such tools included, but not sure. Even if it is true then also this may not be applicable to "PROJECT A", some old clients are still using old runtimes.

"PROJECT B" is created using C#, which initiate to create Memory & Thread Dumps using JMAP and JSTACK. It find these command in relevant folder and run them to collected the dump files.

Question: Is there any other way to create this dumps without using JMAP or JSTACK.

I have gone through many discussion threads on STACKOVERFLOW but couldn't find related solution.

Comment: Has anyone tried this using C++ ?

Comment: Since about Java1.6_40 you can make a regular process dump and then extract heap and stack trace using jmap and jstack. This way there is no need to install JDK on client machine.

Comment: @Banthar : I am not a java programmer, Can you elaborate how to do this.

Comment: It's a regular process dump. On windows it can be created, for example, [using task manager](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/931673). jmap and jstack can extract Java specific information from such core dump.

Comment: I have tried that but it is not what I require. I am trying to create Memory dump and Thread dump of JVM programmatically.